# How to scale a coordinate system?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a bunch of coordinates and I draw them on a Bitmap Image to then display them on an Image control in a Wpf application.

Given data to take into consideration:

- My Bitmap File is `1000 * 1000`
- The Bitmap File gets filled in a `660 * 440` Image Control
- (0,0) of my coordinate system is (500,500) in the Bitmap File, so (330, 220) of the Image Control.

Now what I am trying to accomplish is to highlight the coordinates that are near my Mouse.

Other things to take into consideration:

- Mouse Position is given with respect to the Image Control
- Y-Axis is inverted on the Bitmap (0,0) is at top and (0, max) is at bottom (but don't get confused on this one, simply once we finish all the calculations we then just flip all Ys of our coordinates - will be displayed correct)

Now if you love programming, [**this is what I am stuck on right now**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400410/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-coordinate-with-respect-to-mouse-position). But here, I will use my **awesome** Painting *Skills* I explain the problem:

[image]

Comment: What about x/660*1000-500?

Comment: `DesiredX = CurrentPosition/660*100-500` is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, apart your 100 which should be 1000.

Comment: It is the answer if you want to post it @Aretino Thanks )))